# Exclude Junction-Points in Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell, get-childitem, junction

I'd like to get a list of all user-created folders in the `C:\` drive. However I'm getting false results because of junction points.
I tried

```
$generalExclude += @("Users", "LocalData", "PerfLogs", "Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "ProgramData", "sysdat", "Windows", "eplatform", "Intel", "Recovery",  "OneDriveTemp")

Get-ChildItem "\\localhost\c$" -Directory -force -Exclude $generalExclude -ErrorAction 'silentlycontinue' | Where-Object $_.Attributes.ToString() -NotLike "ReparsePoint"
```

But I get a

> You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression error.

Comment: `Where-Object Attributes -NotLike "*ReparsePoint*"` as `-NotLike` comparison operator requires wildcard character(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are missing the `braces{}` for your `scriptblock` in your `Where-Object` cmdlet. Also the `-notlike` operator uses wildcard for search operation.

```
Get-ChildItem "\\localhost\c$" -Directory -force -Exclude $generalExclude -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Where-Object {$_.Attributes.ToString() -NotLike "*ReparsePoint*"}
```

As per the [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) document for the `Where-Object` cmdlet, you will see there are two ways to construct a Where-Object command.

**Method 1**

> **Script block**.
>
> You can use a script block to specify the property name, a comparison
>   operator, and a property value. Where-Object returns all objects for
>   which the script block statement is true.
>
> For example, the following command gets processes in the Normal
>   priority class, that is, processes where the value of the
>   PriorityClass property equals Normal.
>
> ```
> Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.PriorityClass -eq "Normal"}
> ```

**Method 2**

> **Comparison statement**.
>
> You can also write a comparison statement, which is much more like
>   natural language. Comparison statements were introduced in Windows
>   PowerShell 3.0.
>
> For example, the following commands also get processes that have a
>   priority class of Normal. These commands are equivalent and can be
>   used interchangeably.
>
> ```
> Get-Process | Where-Object -Property PriorityClass -eq -Value "Normal"
>
> Get-Process | Where-Object PriorityClass -eq "Normal"
> ```

Additional Info -

> Starting in Windows PowerShell 3.0, Where-Object adds comparison
>   operators as parameters in a Where-Object command. Unless specified,
>   all operators are case-insensitive. Prior to Windows PowerShell 3.0,
>   the comparison operators in the Windows PowerShell language could be
>   used only in script blocks.

In your case, you are constructing the `Where-Object` as a `scriptblock` and hence `braces{}` become a necessary evil. Alternatively, you can construct your `Where-Object` in the following ways -

```
Get-ChildItem "\\localhost\c$" -Directory -force -Exclude $generalExclude -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Where-Object Attributes -NotLike "*ReparsePoint*"
```

**(OR)**

```
Get-ChildItem "\\localhost\c$" -Directory -force -Exclude $generalExclude -erroraction 'silentlycontinue' | Where-Object -property Attributes -NotLike -value "*ReparsePoint*"
```

Answer (score -1):

There's an attributes parameter for this purpose.

```
$generalExclude = 'Users', 'LocalData', 'PerfLogs', 'Program Files',
  'Program Files (x86)', 'ProgramData', 'sysdat', 'Windows','eplatform', 'Intel',
  'Recovery', 'OneDriveTemp'
get-childItem c:\ -attributes !reparsepoint -directory -force `
  -exclude $generalexclude -erroraction silentlycontinue
```

Example showing a reparsepoint:

```
get-childItem c:\ -attributes reparsepoint -force

    Directory: C:\
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d--hsl          8/7/2019   7:37 PM                Documents and Settings
```